# Freeform Pro Text field type is not installed but is showing a lock icon

Tags: ee2, solspace-freeform

I'm trying to install the Freeform Pro Text field type. Its not installed but is showing a lock icon. I don't know how to install the filed type. Any thoughts.

Comment: Glad you tracked the issue down. Make sure to select your answer as the "correct" one by clicking the checkbox to the left of the answer. Might be a time delay before you can click...

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that I needed to update Freeform to the latest version.